# Representing strings numerically for a RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, recurrent-neural-network, tensor

[image]

I have a dataset with two variables like the attached photo. I am trying to represent these numerically so that I can predict the target variable sectionName. Whenever I use keras' texts_to_sequences function it creates an object array like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]   for example.

This produces the error: ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor).

Any advice on how to get around this? Or pointers on whether this is the best method of going about numerically representing these strings?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can represent text numerically with a tokenizer. A basic tokenizer transforms each word to a number. Like this:

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=10000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(list_text)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(list_text)
```

So, basically you neet to fit the tokenizer first with you dataset then you can use it to tokenize.